# new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager() shows error in Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im using a `viewpager` in a `fragment` from `navigation drawer`.

The error is Cannot resolve method `'getSupportFragmentManager()'` in viewpager.

In Code :

```
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My whole Code is:
GalleryFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {


    private static GalleryFragment instance = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery,container,false);

        return v;
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Image Gallery"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Video Gallery"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
    public static GalleryFragment newInstance(String text) {

        if (instance == null) {
            // new instance
            instance = new GalleryFragment();

            // sets data to bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("msg", text);

            // set data to fragment
            instance.setArguments(bundle);

            return instance;
        } else {

            return instance;
        }

    }
```

fragment_gallery.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.GalleryFragment">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

Can Anyone please help me to figure my error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `getFragmentManager()` in a `Fragment`. If the Fragment is from the support library the returned value of  `getFragmentManager()` is the one from the supported library.